# How to find and replace the first occurrence of any single text character (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to replace or substitute the first instance of a single text character in an excel row.

```
current: B01 TEST TEST TEST A W B 0 A
expected result where first "A" that is on its own is replaced with "|": B01 TEST TEST TEST | W B 0 A
```

The issue is, each row has a character that is segmented on its own, but they are all different (some A, some W, some R, etc). Which function can I use to look for the first instance of a single text character surrounded by spaces?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  How is what you have tried so far failing?  Are you familiar with the [`REPLACE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/find-findb-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628), [`SUBSTITUTE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332), and [`FIND`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/find-findb-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628) functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses Office 365 LET and SEQUENCE and is not dependent on it being a capital character.  It will replace the first character whether alpha, numeric or special that has a space on either side of it with the `|`:

```
=LET(rng,A1,
    sq,SEQUENCE(LEN(rng)-3),
    md,MID(rng,sq,3),
    lft,LEFT(md),
    rt,RIGHT(md),
    REPLACE(rng,MIN(IF((lft=" ")*(rt=" "),sq+1)),1,"|"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Office 365 you could use `=AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND(" "&CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,65))&" ",A19),1)`

Older version: `=AGGREGATE(15,6,FIND(" "&{"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"}&" ",A19),1)`

Edit: better version suggested by Mayukh

`=AGGREGATE (15,6,FIND(" "&CHAR(ROW($65:$90))&" ",A19),1)`